# httpServletRequest.remoteUser is null, it doesn't show my logged in user?

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I want to show the user who is logged-in using thymeleaf, but it seems it doesnt save the username even though i logged in succefully. I used `#httpServletRequest.remoteUser` in `/bidList/list.html`:

```html
<div class="col-6 text-right" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    Logged in user: <b th:inline="text" class="user"> [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]] </b>
    <form th:action="@{/app-logout}" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**The error:**

```java
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/bidList/list.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/bidList/list.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: An error happened during template rendering

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateOutputException: An error happened during template rendering

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#httpServletRequest.remoteUser" (template: "bidList/list" - line 21, col 57)

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'remoteUser' cannot be found on null
```

**Security configuration**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
   @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Secure the http access
     *
     * @param http HttpSecurity
     * @return http
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers( "/", "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                //Authentication request parameters
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                )
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        //.usernameParameter("user.username")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/bidList/list", true)
                )
                //logout
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll()
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app-logout"))
                        //Definition of the default logout success URL
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        //Invalidate the current HTTP session and its cookies
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                )
                //In case of exception of an access denied
                .exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling) -> exceptionHandling.accessDeniedPage("/app/error"));

        return http.build();
    }

    /**
     *Bcrypt uses hash algorithm to store password
     *
     * @return passwordEncoder
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Function for allowing the loading of the static resources
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.debug(true)
                .ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/css/**");
    }
```

**CustomUserDetailsService:**

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), getGrantedAuthorities(user.getRole()));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
        return authorities;
    }
```

I tried using `#authentication.principal.firstName`
but i got the same error with a difference:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on null
```

Comment: can you try `#authentication.getName()`?

Comment: Trying #authentication.getName() gets me the same error : Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getName() on null context object